# OpenLayers GeoJSON Layer projection not working

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers-3, projection

Using the code below, I've been unable to get my single GeoJSON point feature to appear on the map.  Or possibly if it does appear on the map in the correct location.  It appears in Germany, whereas it should appear in Tasmania, Australia.  Same location it appears at if I provide no projection at all.  Therefore it seems that there is some problem with the way I'm setting the projection.

I have a feeling that I'm using `defaultDataProjection` and/or `featureProjection` incorrectly, but I find the documentation to be fairly unclear on how these should be used.

The same projection works on my other (non-GeoJSON) layers OK.

How can I correct my code to get this to work?

```js
var geojsonObject = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[503619.026899999939,5420925.347199999727]},"properties":{"label":{}},"type":"Feature"}]};

proj4.defs('layerProj', '+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ')

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        defaultDataProjection: 'layerProj',
    }).readFeatures(geojsonObject, { featureProjection: 'layerProj' }))
})

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({image: new ol.style.Circle({fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#8888FF'}), radius: 10, points: 0})}),
});
    
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `format:` should be `features:`  Also `defaultDataProjection` in the GeoJSON options in OpenLayers 4 changes to `dataProjection` in later version, so it may be better to specify `dataProjection` in the `readFeatures` options where the name is the same in all versions.  `featureProjection` should always be set to the view projection

```
        features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject, { 
          dataProjection: 'layerProj',
          featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
        })
```

If you are using OpenLayers 5 or above you will also need to register proj4 after the `layerproj` definition

```
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
```

Comment: The `format:` was a typo.  I had `features:` in my code.  Not sure how that changed in my copy/paste to here.  I've fixed this in the original question now.  Thanks for the rest of the information.  I'll give it a shot and report back.  Also, I'm using OL 3 (very old school!  I  need to update one day!)

Comment: Thank you.  Your configuration of the `dataProjection:` and `featureProjection:` was spot on.  My GeoJSON features are now displayed perfectly on my OL3 map.  Thanks again!